# How to create mutiple arrays from a text file and loop through the values of each array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, scripting

I have a text file with the following:

```
Paige
Buckley
Govan
Mayer
King

Harrison
Atkins
Reinhardt
Wilson

Vaughan
Sergovia
Tarrega
```

My goal is to create an array for each set of names. Then Iterate through the first array of values then move on to the second array of values and lastly the third array. Each set is separated by a new line in the text file. Help with code or logic is much appreciated!

so far I have the following. i am unsure of the logic moving forward when i reach a line break. My research here also suggests that i can use `readarray -d`.

```
#!/bin/bash

my_array=()
while IFS= read -r line || [[ "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line -eq "" ]]; 
.
.
.

        arr+=("$line") # i know this adds the value to the array
done < "$1"
printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
```

desired output:

```
array1 = (Paige Buckley6 Govan Mayer King)
array2 = (Harrison Atkins Reinhardt Wilson)
array3 = (Vaughan Sergovia Terrega)
#then loop through the each array one after the other.
```

Comment: Do you really need those arrays? If you plan to loop over them one after another, then why not do the task you plan to do right away when reading the file?

Comment: Also, isn't this [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66411839/6770384)? I see you improved it by a lot. However, next time your question gets closed, please edit it and ask the persons who closed it to *reopen*. They didn't close your question for eternity but rather asked you to improve it.

Comment: `My goal is to create an array for each set of names` Is this really __your goal__? It sounds more like a small step for something else.

Comment: @Socowi thank you for your input! The logic behind this is part of a larger program. Unfortunately they need to be in separate arrays as certain conditions need to be met.   If I were to combine the arrays I would later need to separate them in the code. Initially this is one long text file. I have an awk statement to break the text sets to n values.  That was my question. I'll will note this moving forward.

Comment: On the surface this is easier to do in awk, if we define the _record separator_ as `\n\n` and the _field separator_ as `\n`. My concern is that it doesn't feel like bash is the right tool for the "larger program": the needed data structures aren't there.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has no array-of-arrays. So you have to represent it in an other way.

You could leave the newlines and have an array of newline separated elements:

```
array=()

elem=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" != "" ]]; then
        elem+="${elem:+$'\n'}$line" # accumulate lines in elem
    else
        array+=("$elem")  # flush elem as array element
        elem=""
    fi
done 
if [[ -n "$elem" ]]; then
   array+=("$elem") # flush the last elem
fi

# iterate over array
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};++i)); do
    # each array element is newline separated items
    readarray -t elem <<<"${array[i]}"
    printf 'array%d = (%s)\n' "$i" "${elem[*]}"
done
```

You could simplify the loop with some unique character and a `sed` for example like:

```
readarray -d '#' -t array < <(sed -z 's/\n\n/#/g' file)
```

But overall, this `awk` generates same output:

```
awk -v RS= -v FS='\n' '{ 
     printf "array%d = (", NR;
     for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s%s", $i, i==NF?"":" ";
     printf ")\n"
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using nameref :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a array1 array2 array3

declare -n array=array$((n=1))

while IFS= read -r line; do
    test "$line" = "" && declare -n array=array$((n=n+1)) || array+=("$line")
done < "$1"

declare -p array1 array2 array3
```

Called with :

```
bash test.sh data
# result
declare -a array1=([0]="Paige" [1]="Buckley" [2]="Govan" [3]="Mayer" [4]="King")
declare -a array2=([0]="Harrison" [1]="Atkins" [2]="Reinhardt" [3]="Wilson")
declare -a array3=([0]="Vaughan" [1]="Sergovia" [2]="Tarrega")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- blank links are truly blank (ie, no need to worry about any white space on said lines)
- could have consecutive blank lines
- names could have embedded white space
- the number of groups could vary and won't always be `3` (as with the sample data provided in the question)
- OP is open to using a (simulated) 2-dimensional array as opposed to a (variable) number of 1-dimensional arrays

My data file:

```
$ cat names.dat
                       <<< leading blank lines

Paige
Buckley
Govan
Mayer
King Kong

                       <<< consecutive blank lines

Harrison
Atkins
Reinhardt
Wilson

Larry
Moe
Curly
Shemp

Vaughan
Sergovia
Tarrega

                       <<< trailing blank lines
```

One idea that uses a couple arrays:

- array #1: associative array - the previously mentioned (simulated) 2-dimensional array with the index - `[x,y]` - where `x` is a unique identifier for a group of names and `y` is a unique identifier for a name within a group
- array #2: 1-dimensional array to keep track of `max(y)` for each group `x`

Loading the arrays:

```
unset      names max_y                     # make sure array names are not already in use
declare -A names                           # declare associative array

x=1                                        # init group counter
y=0                                        # init name counter
max_y=()                                   # initialize the max(y) array
inc=                                       # clear increment flag

while read -r name
do
    if [[ "${name}" = '' ]]                # if we found a blank line ...
    then
        [[ "${y}" -eq 0 ]]   &&            # if this is a leading blank line then ...
        continue                           # ignore and skip to the next line

        inc=y                              # set flag to increment 'x'
    else
        [[ "${inc}" = 'y' ]] &&            # if increment flag is set ...
        max_y[${x}]="${y}"   &&            # make note of max(y) for this 'x'
        ((x++))              &&            # increment 'x' (group counter)
        y=0                  &&            # reset 'y'
        inc=                               # clear increment flag

        ((y++))                            # increment 'y' (name counter)

        names[${x},${y}]="${name}"         # save the name
    fi

done < names.dat

max_y[${x}]="${y}"                         # make note of the last max(y) value
```

Contents of the array:

```
$ typeset -p names
declare -A names=([1,5]="King Kong" [1,4]="Mayer" [1,1]="Paige" [1,3]="Govan" [1,2]="Buckley" [3,4]="Shemp" [3,3]="Curly" [3,2]="Moe" [3,1]="Larry" [2,4]="Wilson" [2,2]="Atkins" [2,3]="Reinhardt" [2,1]="Harrison" [4,1]="Vaughan" [4,2]="Sergovia" [4,3]="Tarrega" )


$ for (( i=1; i<=${x}; i++ ))
do
    for (( j=1; j<=${max_y[${i}]}; j++ ))
    do
        echo "names[${i},${j}] : ${names[${i},${j}]}"
    done
    echo ""
done

names[1,1] : Paige
names[1,2] : Buckley
names[1,3] : Govan
names[1,4] : Mayer
names[1,5] : King Kong

names[2,1] : Harrison
names[2,2] : Atkins
names[2,3] : Reinhardt
names[2,4] : Wilson

names[3,1] : Larry
names[3,2] : Moe
names[3,3] : Curly
names[3,4] : Shemp

names[4,1] : Vaughan
names[4,2] : Sergovia
names[4,3] : Tarrega
```